# Css3 columns horizontal overflow

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble trying to get a desired page layout to work by using HTML5/CSS3 only (without needing JavaScript).

The basic concepts are...

1. A page with a header and body (static).
2. The body has several "sections" which each have a header and body (static).
3. The sections flow from left-to-right (you scroll the page body horizontally to see the sections if they overflow).
4. The sections have a fluid height and width (height adjusts to the size of the page body, width adjusts based on the contents or a min of 300px).
5. The fields within the section body flow from top-to-bottom. When there is overflow, the fields overflowing should move to a new column and the section body should expand dynamically. The should not be broken apart if they overflow to a new column (the label and input should be moved together).

NOTE: I'm testing in IE11 currently but ultimately the solution should be functional in the latest Chrome/FF/IE/Safari versions.

I can't seem to get the section body to expand when the fields overflow into new columns while still retaining the column behavior.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="section">
            <div class="sectionheader">Section 1</div>
            <div class="sectionbody">
                <div class="field">
                    <label>Field 1</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                </div>
                <!-- NOTE: repeat field element to create 5 or more fields... -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- NOTE: repeat section element to create more sections... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body, .container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: gray;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.header {
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
}
.body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 40px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.section {
    min-height: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid red;
    margin-right: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.sectionheader {
    height: 40px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20pt;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.sectionbody {
    white-space: normal;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: white;
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
    column-count: auto;
    -webkit-column-count: auto;
    column-width: 320px;
    -webkit-column-width: 320px;
    column-fill: auto;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
}
.field {
    margin: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.field label {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: block;
}
.field input {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t7kQ4/7/

(drag the handle to adjust the height of the result pane to trigger the field overflow)

Answer (score 0):

Does this help: http://jsfiddle.net/t7kQ4/10/

You need to remove the calc you are performing and allow it to be auto.

```
section { 
  height:auto;
}
.sectionbody {
  height:auto;
}
```

Comment: thanks @jsmartfo, With height: auto, the sections height expands with the content and the bottom of the section gets pushed down out of view. Ideally, the section's top+bottom should always be viewable and fields should wrap into separate columns horizontally.

Comment: which leads me to this question... what is the reason for hiding the scroll? overflow-y: hidden;

Comment: The intention is to only have horizontal scrolling (similar to windows 8). overflow-y: hidden was added to hide anything that was overflowing vertically. But it really shouldn't be needed if the sections didn't occupy more than 100% of the page body. But when using CSS columns, the container (sectionbody) is not expanding. (See original fiddle)